Seeking Comprehensive Back Workout Suggestions with Cable Machine
I'm in search of a comprehensive back workout lasting around 1-2 hours, specifically utilizing the cable machine. So far, I've thought of including:

Lat pull-downs
Seated cable rows

I'm uncertain about which other exercises might provide a full back workout.
Does anyone have suggestions for a workout plan or additional exercises that target various back muscles?

And you want to use exclusively cable machines?

If your cable machine has a bar on top of it you can do pull ups. If pull ups are too hard, use resistance bands to make them easier

@Luciano Nopes, it can be anything

So you are asking about a full back workout using the cable machine or just a full back workout with any other equipment? I'm a bit confused here. What else do you have available?
